# "It's fast and in motion."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [Metro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_Design_Language) is our design language. We call it Metro because it's modern and clean. It's fast and **in motion**. It's about content and typography. And it's entirely authentic.

In this context, what the 'in motion' means and makes you feel what?

If it refer to the elements in UI, then it seems that every UI design contains some movable elements. In that case, it is just a superfluous word.

Comment: Why don't people pay more attention to question titles? Let me ask you: Is your question really about the "Metro UI of Microsoft" or about what "in motion" means?  The former would seem an uninteresting and on-topic title to any bypasser who might be able to answer your question. So, if the latter, why don't you make that clear in your title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In motion" means it is something that is moving.

A car can be fast but not moving just at the moment. Something can be moving right now but not be very fast. The copywriter is assuring you that Metro has both desirable qualities.

*Metro* is an abbreviation of *metropolitan*, meaning "having to do with a large city" and also describes the subway system of Paris and some other cities, including the one that services Microsoft's home state. The Metro in Paris is fast, efficient (at least when I've ridden it) and a model of public transportation.

The copywriter wants you to feel something positive about the product. Are the words superfluous? Probably to the extent that all advertising seems superfluous to someone who does not wish to be sold a product. But to the extent that people read advertising uncritically, probably they make the right impression.